# Not getting any response - Express Validator

Tags: node.js, validation, express, express-validator

I'm using the latest version of express-validator for validation.
I'm not getting any response, However Old method i.e `checkBody` is working fine while new method i.e `check('keyName')` is not working properly.

Below is my code.

**package.json**

```
"express-validator": "^5.0.3",
```

**routes.js**

```
var authValidator = require('./../validation/auth.validation');
var routes = require('express').Router();

routes.post('/login', [
  authValidator.validateLogin, 
  authValidator.checkValidationResult ], function (req, res) {
     console.log('3');
     //res.send("Some other stuffs");
  }
);

module.exports = routes;
```

**auth.validation.js**

```
module.exports.validateLogin = validateLogin;
module.exports.checkValidationResult = checkValidationResult;

const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator/check');
const {matchedData, sanitize} = require('express-validator/filter');

var response = require('./../general/MyResponse');
var messages = require('./../general/messages');

function validateLogin(req, res, next) {
  console.log('1');
  return [
    check('email').isLength({min: 1}).withMessage(messages.EMAIL_REQUIRED)
    .isEmail().withMessage(messages.INVALID_EMAIL),
    check('password').isLength({min: 1}).withMessage(messages.PASSWORD_REQUIRED),
  ]
}

function checkValidationResult(req, res, next) {
  console.log('2');
  var result = validationResult(req)
  if (!result.isEmpty()) {
    response.createResponse(
      res, 400,
      result.array()[0].msg,
      {'error': result.array()[0].msg}, {}
    )
  } else {
    next()
  }
}
```

I've noticed that node js not able to go ahead from the function `validateLogin` in `auth.validation.js`.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with above code.

Inside console, Only 1 is displaying.

I'm attaching screenShot for referance.

[image: screenShot of error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to use simple Array and don't need to create function.

Follow this link 
[Is it possible to do the validation in a separate file and not inline in the route? - GitHub](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator/issues/449) for more details.

Code should be like this.

**auth.validation.js**

```
var response = require('./../general/MyResponse');
var messages = require('./../general/messages');

const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator/check');
const {matchedData, sanitize} = require('express-validator/filter');

module.exports.validateLogin = [
    check('email').isLength({min: 1}).withMessage(messages.EMAIL_REQUIRED).isEmail().withMessage(messages.INVALID_EMAIL),
    check('password').isLength({ min: 1 }).withMessage(messages.PASSWORD_REQUIRED),
];

module.exports.checkValidationResult = checkValidationResult;

function checkValidationResult(req, res, next) {
    console.log('2');
    var result = validationResult(req)
    if (!result.isEmpty()) {
        response.createResponse(res, 400,
            result.array()[0].msg,
            {'error': result.array()[0].msg}, {}
        )
    } else {
        next()
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Dead-code: `const {matchedData, sanitize} = require('express-validator/filter');`

Comment: I'm using sanitize method in other validation function that's why i declared constant there.

Comment: The entire /check requirement is deprecated, but otherwise this is a great answer

Answer (score 1):

`validateLogin` and `checkValidationResult` are being applied as middlewares to your route. In middlewares you use `next()`method to call next middleware in the queue. Just like in your `checkValidationResult`.

In case of `validateLogin`, its not passing control to next middleware. But `check` method from `express-validator` v5 is itself a middleware method. Thus I guess it won't work correctly.

Please have a look at: https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator/issues/449

Try using following Code:

**routes.js**

```
var authValidator = require('./../validation/auth.validation');
var routes = require('express').Router();
var authValidations = authValidator.getAuthValidations();

routes.post('/login', 
  authValidations,
  authValidator.checkValidationResult, function (req, res) {
     console.log('3');
     //res.send("Some other stuffs");
  }
);

module.exports = routes;
```

**auth.validations.js**

```
module.exports.getAuthValidations = getAuthValidations;
module.exports.checkValidationResult = checkValidationResult;

const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator/check');
const {matchedData, sanitize} = require('express-validator/filter');

var response = require('./../general/MyResponse');
var messages = require('./../general/messages');

function getAuthValidations(req, res, next) {
  return [
    check('email').isLength({min: 1}).withMessage(messages.EMAIL_REQUIRED)
    .isEmail().withMessage(messages.INVALID_EMAIL),
    check('password').isLength({min: 1}).withMessage(messages.PASSWORD_REQUIRED),
  ]
}

function checkValidationResult(req, res, next) {
  console.log('2');
  var result = validationResult(req)
  if (!result.isEmpty()) {
    response.createResponse(
      res, 400,
      result.array()[0].msg,
      {'error': result.array()[0].msg}, {}
    )
  } else {
    next()
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be more helpful if you provided examples.

Comment: Dead-code: `const {matchedData, sanitize} = require('express-validator/filter');`